# I'm trying to display data from my DB but without column name

Tags: node.js, database

I wrote short webapp using node.js that displays data from my database. Everything works as expected, but I do not know how to format data just to display the column content without column name.

```
function formatData(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        const formattedResults = {};

        const groupedData = data.reduce((groups, item) => {
            const repoName = item.RepositoryNameUnderscored;
            groups[repoName] = groups[repoName] || [];
            groups[repoName].push(item);
            return groups;
        }, {});

        for (const repoName in groupedData) {
            const repoData = groupedData[repoName];

            for (const field in repoData[0]) {
                formattedResults[field] = formattedResults[field] || [];

                if (field === 'RepositoryNameUnderscored') {
                    formattedResults[field].push(repoName);
                } else if (field === 'Role') {
                    const roles = repoData.map(item => item[field]);
                    formattedResults[field].push(`${repoName}: ${roles.join(', ')}`);
                } else if (typeof repoData[0][field]?.value !== 'undefined') {
                    const values = repoData.map(item => item[field].value);
                    formattedResults[field].push(...values);
                } else {
                    const values = repoData.map(item => item[field]);
                    formattedResults[field].push(...values);
                }
            }
        }

        const resultString = Object.entries(formattedResults)
            .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value.join(', ')}`)
            .join('<br>');

        return resultString;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Please help me edit my `formatData` function to not display column name `RepositoryNameUnderscored` but only its content.

Comment: This line here `const resultString = Object.entries(formattedResults)` you're serializing it into HTML, and it looks like this line you want to remove the Key: `.map(([key, value]) => ${value.join(', ')}`)` so you just get Values, not the Key which I expect is the column. Correct me if I've misunderstood?